# animation act weird when pressing play twice

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have created a simple rectangle animation that goes forward and back. The problem is that if I push the start button twice it acting weird.
i want the animation to start from the first position If I press start twice.

any tips ?

```
      function moveRect1()
        {       
            // Reverse.uppfÖrande
            if( xEnd == 150 )
                xEnd = 50;
            else
                xEnd = 150;

            // x heter x på rektanglar. Vänstra övre hörnet.
            rect1.animate( {x: xEnd},                       // det/de attribut som ska animeras, och till vilket värde.
                            1000,                                   // tid
                            "Sine",                         // Ease funktion
function (){ moveRect1(); } // 
        ); // end animation

        }
```

Link to the animation

http://www.pixeltouch.no/multimedia/labb3/svg.php

Comment: can u set it up in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I have a problem runing it on jsfiddle since  I an svg file include, but this is the link where its uploaded.

http://www.pixeltouch.no/multimedia/labb3/svg.php